# Determining the current priority of a pthread (mutex priority inheritance)

Tags: pthreads, thread-priority

I'm experimenting with pthreads, and in order to verify that my understanding of the mutex priority inheritance mechanism is correct, I'd like to determine the current running priority (when holding a mutex) later to be locked by a higher priority thread.

Obviously pthread_getschedparam is NOT the way to go, it just returns the priority/value last (explicitly) set.

1. Is it possible using pthreads API (haven't found it)
2. Is it possible using LinuxThread primitives (there should be 1x1 mapping from NPTL (clib pthreads) to LinuxThreads
3. Is it possible thorough POSIX Thread Trace Tool (PTT) (don't seem so out the box). In such case it would be a welcome extension to the PTT tool for debugging (soft) real-time applications under Linux/NPTL.

Answer (score 0):

The boosted priority is visible in the current priority of the thread as shown by the 18th field in `/proc/<TID>/stat`.

Note that the thread only has its priority boosted while a higher priority thread is actually waiting for the mutex.